# Bootstrapping an interpreter?

Tags: language-agnostic, compiler-construction, interpreter, bootstrapping

We know that a compiler can be written in its own language using a trick known as bootstrapping.  My question is whether this trick can be applied to interpreters as well?

In theory the answer is certainly yes, but there is one worry that the interpretation of source code will become more and more inefficient as we go through the iterations.  Would that be a serious problem?

I'm bootstrapping a very dynamical system where the programs will be constantly changing, so it rules out a compiler.

Let me spell it out this way:

Let the i's be interpreters.

Let the L's be programming languages.

- We can write i1 in machine code (lowest level), to interpret L1.
- We then write i2 in L1, interpreting L2 -- a new language.
- We then write i3 in L2, interpreting L3 -- another new language.
- and so on...

We don't need any compiler above, just interpreters.  Right?

It could be inefficient.  That is my question, and how to overcome it if it is indeed inefficient.

Comment: If you don't know if this is possible, you almost certainly should not try to create your own programming language. Also, it is not true that you cannot have a dynamic system which is compiled.

Comment: This is not really bootstrapping. Bootstrapping means you compile a language A on a compiler written in language A. This cannot be applied to interpreters, because if interpreter B is interpreting an interpreter for itself, and there is _no_ other language involved, then where exactly is B running? Logic tells us that there must be another language (probably machine code) involved, which means something was compiled. What you're talking about is an interpreter stack. The PyPy project has some experience building a Python interpreter in Python (albeit a restricted subset): http://pypy.org.

Answer (score 6):

That doesn't make sense. An interpreter doesn't produce a binary, so can't create something that can run itself standalone. Somewhere, ultimately, you need to have a binary that is the interpreter.

Example of a compiler bootstrapping. Let's say we have two languages A(ssembler) and C. We want to bootstrap a C compiler written in C. But we only have an assembler to start with.

1. Write basic C compiler in A
2. Write C compiler in C and compile with earlier compiler written in A
3. You now have a C compiler which can compile itself, you don't need A or the original compiler any more.

Later runs become just

1. Compile C program using compiler written in C

Now let's say you have an interpreted language instead, I'll call it Y. The first version can be called Y1, the next Y2 and so on. Let's try to "bootstrap" it.

First off we don't have anything that can interpret Y programs, we need to write a basic interpreter. Let's say we have a C compiler and write a Y1 interpreter in C.

1. Write Y1 interpreter in C, compile it
2. Write Y2 interpreter in Y1, run it on Y1 interpreter written in C
3. Write Y3 interpreter in Y2, run it on Y2 interpreter running on Y1 interpreter... Written in C.

The problem is that you can never escape the stack of interpreters as you never compile a higher level interpreter. So you're always going to need to compile and run that first version interpreter written in C. You can never escape it, which I think is the fundamental point of the compiler bootstrapping process. This is why I say your question does not make sense.

Comment: It does makes sense, albeit not efficiently:  an interpreter takes a program and executes it (without generating a binary);  now what if we feed a newer version of the interpreter to itself?  It will start interpreting in the new way.  No binary is needed.  So, it works;  the question is how to make it efficient.

Comment: It does make sense, even if the interpreters are stacked up -- it's just a form of recursion.  And step 1 does not need a compiler either, it can be an interpreter, with no code output.
My question is precisely how to make it efficient, and partial evaluation may be the answer (a friend just told me).

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on what is being interpreted. If you're targeting a virtual machine which interprets bytecode, and your language is being developed iteratively while the bytecode doesn't change, then it is not a given that you will lose performance along the way. There are plenty of examples of languages which are bootstrapped on a target VM which wasn't designed particularly for that language, and they don't suffer a significant performance hit as a direct result (Scala on the JVM, for instance).

Using the JVM for example, you'd write the first compiler in Java, which compiles your source language to JVM bytecode. Then you'd rewrite your compiler to do exactly the same thing but in your new source language. The resulting bytecode could be indistinguishable between the two. Note that this is not the same thing as writing an interpreter in an interpreted language, which will become slower with each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

This sentence does not seem to make sense:

> I'm bootstrapping a very dynamical system where the programs will be constantly changing, so it rules out a compiler.

No matter if you have an interpreter or a compiler: both will have to deal with something that is *not* changing, i.e. with your language. And even if the language is somehow "dynamic", then there will be a meta-language that is fixed. Most probably you also have some low-level code, or at least a data structure the interpreter is working with.

You could first design and formalize this low-level code (whatever it is) and write some program that can "run" this. Once you have this, you can add a stack of interpreters and as long as they all produce this low level code, efficiency should not be an issue.

Comment: See my edit -- I'm upset that I received many down votes because apparently people don't understand my question...

Comment: Also, in my example, nothing is fixed (other than machine code), and the languages keep changing.  It seems to contradict your opinion that this is impossible.

Answer (score -1):

You can indeed, and this is the approach used by squeak (and I believe many other smalltalks). Here is one approach to doing just that: https://github.com/yoshikiohshima/SqueakBootstrapper/blob/master/README

Comment: Can you explain the process in English? :)

Comment: @YanKingYin No, it's not my project. Once again, if this is too complex for you, you should not be embarking on creating a new language. The world has many, many, programming languages already, and you are likely to be reinventing the wheel unless you already know a lot about existing languges and language design.

Comment: I'm implementing an inductive and abductive fuzzy-probabilistic higher-order logical-functional language, that can potentially understand English.  I have been researching this topic for 8 years, but only recently do I realize that bootstrapping is highly desirable to implement it.  So I'm learning that aspect now... :)

Comment: Also, that web page you linked talks about a Squeak compiler but there's no mention of an interpreter being bootstrapped....

Comment: @YanKingYin It's dynamically compiled and interpreted.